Is there any way to generate Cypress tests from YML in Python?
I want to write end-to-end testcases for web ui, is there any way to generate cypress test cases in python from yaml documentation?
For example, I have test steps written in yaml
methods:
  ssoLogin:
    desc: sso login
    steps:
      - webInput(id,login-username, ytx)
      - webClick(id,btn-login-nopwd)

And the expected spec.js file might be
describe('Test scope 1', () => {
  it('ssoLogin', () => {
    cy.visit("xxx.com/sson/login?client_");        
  
    cy.get('#login-username').should('be.visible').clear().type('ytx', { delay: 100 });

    cy.get('#btn-login-nopwd').should('be.visible').click();
    cy.wait(1000 * 5)
  });
});

Is there any way to write functions in JavaScript with the Cypress framework and pass arguments to them, then tidy test steps, in Python?

The YML format is XML based and looks completely different from the YAML format, which is
what you have. The recommended file extension for YAML files has been  .yaml since 2006.

@leslie this is not a question about YAML, applying the tag is as informative as applying the tag ASCII or UTF-8, read the tag definition
